# Update multiple sheet in specific sequence

Tags: refresh

i have a question:

I have a workbook with multiple sheet.

I want to create a macro to refresh multiple sheet in the specific sequence i want.

At the end, give us a message "Done" and save the workbook.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried to do the refresh.all, however it gets stuck because its to info. So the only solution is to update in a specific sequence.